# Check if part of array is included

Tags: ruby, arrays

Let's say I have a array:

```
newArray = Array.[]
```

And then I push some strings in it:

```
newArray.push 'nil'  
newArray.push 'nil2'  
newArray.push 'nil3'
```

Now I make a while loop:

```
while true  
    load = gets.chomp

    if newArray[].include? load  
        puts 'That pieace of the Array is loaded' 
        break 
    end  
end
```

The part `if newArray[].include? load` is wrong, I know. But how can I make it so this will work?

Comment: So you want to check if `load` is in the array OR if `load` is a substring of one of the elements in the array?

Comment: Pretty confident when he says ``part of array is loaded`` he actually means ``that element exists``.

Comment: Yes, what Nobita says!

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I want to check if load is a substring of one of the elements in the array, by only typing 0/1/2 (one of those options)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is confusing, and your code isn't idiomatic Ruby. Consider writing it like:

```
new_array = []
new_array << 'nil'
new_array << 'nil2'
new_array << 'nil3'

loop do
  load = gets.chomp

  if new_array.include? load
    puts 'That piece of the Array is loaded'
    break
  end
end
```

- We use snake_case_for_variables becauseItIsALotEasierToRead.
- While we *can* write `Array.new` or `Array.[]`, we seldom do. We usually assign `[]` to a variable instead.
- We typically `push` to an array using `<<`. It's shorter to type, and visually sets apart what's happening.
- Use `loop do` instead of `while true`.

I'd actually be more straightforward when defining that array:

```
new_array = %w[nil nil2 nil3]
```

And I'd use more mnemonic variable names so the code is more self-documenting:

```
ary = %w[nil nil2 nil3]

loop do
  user_input = gets.chomp

  if ary.include? user_input
    puts 'That piece of the Array is loaded'
    break
  end
end
```

If you want to see if the value entered is part of a string element in the array:

```
if ary.any? { |s| s[user_input] }
  puts 'That piece of the Array is loaded'
  break
end
```

If you want to see if the value entered is the last character of a string element in the array:

```
if ary.any? { |s| s[-1] == user_input }
```

or:

```
if ary.any? { |s| s[/#{ user_input }$/] }
```

Read [the documentation for `any?`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F) to understand what it's doing.